# Any difference in nuance between “for easing restrictions” and “for easing of restrictions”?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, gerunds

These days, we often see news headlines like the below examples, and I wonder if there is any difference in nuance between **"for easing restrictions"** and **"for easing of restrictions"**. Can anyone help me with this question, please.

**Greek government unveils plan for easing restrictions.** https://knews.kathimerini.com.cy/en/news/greek-government-unveils-plan-for-easing-restrictions

**Koike unveils road map for easing of restrictions in Tokyo** https://japantoday.com/category/national/Koike-unveils-road-map-for-easing-of-restrictions-in-Tokyo

Comment: The first uses *easing* as a verb. The second uses it as a gerund.

Comment: There's no discernible difference in meaning.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I thought the "easing" in both cases function as gerund.

Comment: @Jim No, that's wrong. The first is as a verb (you can tell because it has a direct object) and the second is as a noun (you can tell because it needs a preposition to attach to another noun). Only the first is what people call a gerund, not the second. Gerunds are always verbs, just ones that happen to be used in a substantive role such as the subject or the object. But there is no difference in nuance between the two formulations here.

Comment: @tchrist - Isn’t that what I said?

Comment: Ok so my calling the noun use a gerund was incorrect?  I’ll admit I was unsure but I thought a gerund was a “ing” form used as a noun.

Comment: @Jim Nope. You called the second a gerund. It isn't. The second is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: @Jim It's more complicated than that. We have a dizzying plethora of questions that cover the matter here.

Comment: It's gratifying to see that the pairings are 'plan to **do**' (more verby, process involved) and 'road map to **final infrastructure solution**' (more nouny, resultative).

Answer (score -1):

*"Verbal nouns are not the same as gerunds (another type of noun formed from a verb). A gerund is a noun that, having derived from a verb, retains a few verb-like properties. For example, a gerund can be modified by an adverb and can take a direct object."*

Source :
https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/verbal_nouns.htm

> [1] In the expression, **"for easing restrictions"**, *'easing'* is a gerund. It's used like a noun as the complement of a preposition 'for' , and it also takes a direct object 'restrictions' like a verb.
>
> [2] In the expression, **"for easing of restrictions"**, *'easing'* is a verbal noun having no verb-like properties.

[Here the noun 'restrictions' is the complement of the preposition 'of'; and the verbal noun 'easing' serves as the complement of the preposition 'for'.]

Comment: (2) A fully deverbal noun usage will be count (and thus pluralise): 'The thieves stole three paintings'. And there's a definite article missing before 'easing' (probably merely an artifact of headlinese).